# How to convert Auth::guard('web') to Auth::guard('user') in Laravel 5.3?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

I have 2 guard in Laravel 5.3: `web` and `admin`.

I need to convert `Auth::guard('web')` to `Auth::guard('user')` in Laravel 5.3?

How to convert `web` to `user`?

After change in `auth.php`:

```
'defaults' => [
    'guard' => 'user',
    'passwords' => 'users',
],

'guards' => [
    'user' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'admin' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'admin',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'token',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
],
'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\User::class,
    ],

    'admin' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Admin::class,
    ],
],
'passwords' => [
    'users' => [
        'provider' => 'users',
        'table' => 'password_resets',
        'expire' => 60,
    ],
],
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should open `config/auth.php`

There you should update `web` to `user` on `guards` array and `defaults` array also in `providers` and `passwords` array and you will have `guard('user')`.

Comment: Yes, after change `web` to `user`, don't work auth::guard('user')

Comment: Please paste your auth.php to your answer and I will review

Comment: Where is providers and passwors arrays? By the way your user and api have same providers

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133590/discussion-between-buglinjo-and-mysun).